# STM32 Blue pill and Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, stm32, bluepill

I want to program Stm32 bluepill with Arduino IDE but when I want to define pins like I write " pinMode(A10, OUTPUT)" it gives error. the error is "'A10' was not declared in this scope"
I want to know how should I declare Pins in Arduino IDE for STM32

Comment: sounds like a syntax error. Post your entire sketch or look at the code around it.

Comment: void setup() {

  pinMode(A10, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(A10, HIGH);   
  delay(1000);                     
  digitalWrite(A10, LOW);   
  delay(1000);                     
}


yeah I think it is syntax, but I dont know how to declare pins,the code is just this

Comment: I compiled this code successfully, may be your configuration is the problem.

Comment: The code has no syntax errors. Did you select the correct board? You'll need to go through the process to load the files for STM so you can select the appropriate board. The Arduino Uno (default) does not have an A10.

Comment: This is what happens when people 1) paste code they don't understand and 2) don't read the datasheet for their parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error you're reporting, you're not building your code for the correct board. I suspect you're targeting the ArduinoUNO (default) which does not have an A10.

Also, as hcheung's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63723538/2250588) mentions, the name on the blue pill is "PA10".

Follow the instructions here to install the board configuration for the STM "blue pill" then select it and build again.

https://maker.pro/arduino/tutorial/how-to-program-the-stm32-blue-pill-with-arduino-ide

Note, the board selection as of today is now "STM32F1 series" instead of "STM32F103C series" as specified at the link.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be there is not ADC pin of number 10 for the currently selected board (check the board on tool -> boards), there might be fewer number of ADC pins, e.g. try A0.

Or maybe you have selected wrong board. Bluepill isn't included in the Arduino IDE, by default. So you have to add it to your IDE first.
There is a nice instruction here on how to do this and a sample code.
https://maker.pro/arduino/tutorial/how-to-program-the-stm32-blue-pill-with-arduino-ide

Remember that this newly installed library could have small differences in syntax compared with standard Arduino code, Like this example that is taken from the mentioned site:

```
void setup() {
  // change pin PC13
  pinMode(PC13, OUTPUT);
}

//infinite loop 
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(PC13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(PC13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

As you can see here the pin is selected using "PC13", and not just a number aka "13".

So in this case by installing the library used in the mentioned site you should write PA0 to PA7 for using ADC.
Here is a sample picture displaying the name of the pins and their features:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried it, same error apeared

Comment: it worked thanks so much, and the pic you sent is so useful

Answer (score 0):

For STM32 Blue Pill with Arduino Core, digital pins are named based on its port and pin number, such as PB1, PA10.

There is no A10, I assumed that you mean PA10 (which was marked on the Blue Pill PCB as "A10" (for Port A Pin 10) due to limit space on the PCB.

To use it as a digital pin, simply use `PA10` to address it, that is:

```
pinMode(PA10, OUTPUT);
```

or because PA10 internally happened to be referred as D10, you can also use:

```
pinMode(10, OUTPUT); //not recommended
```

For better understanding of all the pin assignments for STM32F103 Blue Pill, please take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/master/variants/Generic_F103Cx/variant.h) and [here](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/master/variants/PILL_F103XX/variant.h#L53).

Comment: It worked and your comment was really useful, thanks